# The parameter scale does not work in ggplot2 in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `facet_grid()` to draw multiple plots.

I set `scales = 'free'`, but it didn't work for `facet_1 = 'A', facet_2 = 'a'` and `facet_1 = 'b', facet_2 = 'B'` (Top left and bottom right figures).

**The x-axis range is too big for the two plot.**

```
df = data.frame(
  x = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 60, 0, 60),
  y = c(1.5, 0.3, 1.5, 0.3, 1.8, 0.1, 1.8, 0.1),
  facet_1 = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
  facet_2 = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a'))


df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(facet_1~facet_2, scales = 'free', space = 'free') # scales = 'free_x' also doesn't work
```

[image]

Then, I have to use `patchwork` to replot.

```
df1 = df %>% filter(facet_1 == 'A',facet_2 == 'a') 
df2 = df %>% filter(facet_1 == 'A',facet_2 == 'b') 
df3 = df %>% filter(facet_1 == 'B',facet_2 == 'a') 
df4 = df %>% filter(facet_1 == 'B',facet_2 == 'b') 


p1 = df1 %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + geom_line() 
p2 = df2 %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + geom_line() 
p3 = df3 %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + geom_line() 
p4 = df4 %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + geom_line() 

library(patchwork)

p1+p2+p3+p4
```

[image]

**My question is that is there a method that can draw a plot like using `patchwork` in ggplot with `facet_grid()`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use the `ggh4x` package which offers some useful extensions to overcome some of the limitations of the default `facet_xxx`, e.g. using `ggh4x::facet_grid2` you could do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid2(facet_1~facet_2, scales = "free", independent = "all")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you should use facet_wrap:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(facet_1~facet_2, scales = 'free')
```

Comment: Thanks, Henry.  But can `facet_grid()` do this?

Comment: No. One premise of `facet_grid` is that all facets in one column share the same x-axis, and all facets in one row share the same y-axis.

Comment: why do you want to use facet_grid() so much?